# VirtualBox .vdi drive does not grow

Tags: virtualbox

I have a CentOS guest system in a Windows host. The virtual drive was originally 20 GB, then I resized it to 60 using the `VBoxManage` utility.

VirtualBox reports the expected virtual size (see picture below), but the guest system keeps reporting it's out of storage space. Copying in some files above the limit fails, `df` reports it having only 20 GB for some reason.

[image]

Are there any extra steps I need to take to *actually* increase the size of the drive?

Guest system:
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your disk is now having more space, but your partition still does not. You have to resize also partition to get the additional "physical" space to be available to the OS. As from you question is not clear what Centos version you use, assuming it's Centos7, i may recommend you to use `lvextend`

```
sudo lvextend -L+40G -r /dev/mapper/centos-root
```

Also, i recommend to make a snapshot of your VM hard drive, before doing any actual changes, so you can quickly rollback changes and start over.

Comment: That did the trick. I wonder why there is no mention of this in any of the "how to resize virtualbox disk" guides.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after resizing the partition with GParted and booting up the VM, I also had to **extend the logical volume** and then **grow the file system** to the available size:
(logged in as root)

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/centos/root    

xfs_growfs /dev/centos/root
```

'df -h' then shows the new size.